# Writing a shuffle method in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, shuffle

I'm quite new to learning ruby and I am working through Learn to Program by Chris Pine. One of the exercises he suggests to try out is that of writing a shuffle method (I am aware of the `#shuffle` method). So far, I have come up with this code, which seems to do the job:

```
array_to_shuffle = []
puts "Give me a list of words to shuffle, press enter on an empty line for the result."
input = gets.chomp

while input != ""
  array_to_shuffle = array_to_shuffle.push(input)
  input = gets.chomp
end

def recursive_shuffle(array_to_shuffle, shuffled_array = [])
  return shuffled_array unless array_to_shuffle.size > 0
  array_size = array_to_shuffle.size()
  random_number = rand(1..array_size)-1
  element_transfered = array_to_shuffle [random_number]
  shuffled_array = shuffled_array.push(element_transfered)
  array_to_shuffle.delete(element_transfered)
  recursive_shuffle(array_to_shuffle, shuffled_array)
end

puts recursive_shuffle(array_to_shuffle)
```

However, it is quite long-winded considering what it actually does. Is there any way I could improve on this?

Comment: hmmm seems more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do you want to implement this exact algorithm or do you want to shuffle somehow, just not use `#shuffle`?

Comment: @niceman faire enough! Thanks for the info!

Comment: @ndn I believe this algorithm does the trick of thoroughly shuffling the array, however I might be mistaken ? I am looking to improve upon this algorithm i.e. either finding a more elegant solution.

Comment: Ruby's style conventions strongly encourage dropping empty argument lists: `size()` becomes `size`. This aids considerably in readability, especially when chaining operations. Also instead of `rand(1..n)-1` do `rand(0...n)` where the `...` operator goes up to but does not include the final value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is to pick elements at random until you have picked all elements.

Other than verbosity, another issue that you have is that you use `#delete`. Hence if there are two repeating elements in the array, you will get only one in the shuffled result.

Also you mutate the array passed, which is generally undesirable. Here is an implementation of the same algorithm:

```
def recursive_shuffle(to_shuffle, shuffled = [])
  return shuffled if to_shuffle.empty?
  to_shuffle = to_shuffle.dup if shuffled.empty?

  element = to_shuffle.sample
  to_shuffle.delete_at(to_shuffle.index(element))

  recursive_shuffle(to_shuffle, shuffled + [element])
end
```

---

As for a simpler solution:

```
array.sort_by { rand }
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Would I be correct in saying the shuffled array exists only within the method, as does the to_shuffle array from which the elements are deleted during each round of recursion? This means a second array also named to_shuffle, the initial array where the elements are stored remains unchanged by the recursion and still exists outside the method?

Comment: @Heisenmali, the version I wrote would not change the array that you passed if that is what you are asking. In general, the variables will be local for the method and will not conflict with outside variables.

Comment: Please, do not recommend the "random sorting shuffle" to anybody without mentioning the fact that it is heavily biased and not at all uniform at best, and really just utterly broken: the comparator violates the basic laws of a comparison function and thus the result of the sort is essentially undefined. Really, the only correct way to implement a shuffle is to use the Durstenfeld variation of the Fisher-Yates algorithm (popularized as "Algorithm P" by Donald Knuth in TAOCP) for in-place shuffling, or the inside-out variant for non-destructive shuffling.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I would love to read it if you write it as an answer.